# Proving $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is unique up to unique isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have reading the book "$p$-adic Numbers An Introduction" of Gouvêa and I didn't understand a proof.
In particular, Theorem 3.2.13 states that

> The field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is *unique* up to *unique* isomorphism preserving the absolute value.

If we have another completion $K$, then we can think of the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\hookrightarrow K$ as a map defined on a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. We know that is continous and the extension is unique (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense). The book suggests to perform the same process and then we can consider the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ with $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$. Again, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense and we can uniquely extend. Now the book says that the restriction is the identity of $\mathbb{Q}$ (and this is clear), but I don't see why this is enough to say that we found the inverse.
Can someone help me?
Thanks before!

Comment: We have two maps $f:\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow K, g:K\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_p$ such that $g\circ f =Id_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. However, $g\circ f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, thus $g\circ f=Id_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$. By the same argument we get $f\circ g =Id_K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the composition $\phi \colon \mathbb{Q}_p \to K \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ of your constructed homomorphisms. By construction of the morphisms, $\phi$ is the identity when restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$. Now $\operatorname{id}, \phi \colon \mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ are two extensions of the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$. As you have remarked, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, so extensions are unique. This shows $\phi = \operatorname{id}$.

The same argument shows that $K \to \mathbb{Q}_p \to K$ is also the identity.

Comment: Dense implies extensions are unique ... we would have to know $\phi$ is continuous to do this.  That is where "reserving the absolute value" would be used.

Comment: Now I get it. But I have some problems to see what means "Preserving absolute value". For the inclusion, if I understand, it means "I have the p-adic absolute value in Q, then the absolute value induced by the inclusion is still the p adic absolute value". But when I consider the extension φ I don't get what it means...

Comment: Here the preservation of the absolute value means $\abs{\phi(x)} = \abs{x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: Ok. \abs(x) is the limit of the absolute value of a Cauchy sequence representing x, hence since we know that \abs extends to Q_p (and by assumption, extends also to K), then by the same (x_n) in Q we can define the absolute value and so so the image under φ is the same. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to think about it.